# делегирование конструкторов в Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Сколько ни разбирался, не могу понять, что значит делегирование конструкторов в Java. Прошу помощи разобраться в этом моменте. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все просто - это когда один конструктор может быть вызван другим конструктором изнутри класса с использованием ключевого слова `this` и списка аргументов.

Например, есть класс `Person` и есть конструктор, в котором параметры имя и возраст.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String email;

    public Person(String name, String age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;  
    }
}
```

Допустим мы хотим еще конструктор, но у которого параметры будут имя, возраст и email. Вместо того, чтобы дублировать код из первого конструктора и дописывать еще параметр, типа такого:

```
public Person(String name, String age, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;  
    this.email = email;
}
```

достаточно вызвать другой конструктор с параметрами, а остальное сделать в данном:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String email;

    public Person(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person(String name, String age, String email) {
        this(name, age);
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

А вот еще захотел я конструктор добавить)) Сколько тут дубля можно избежать, можно представить.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String email;
    private String sex;

    public Person(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person(String name, String age, String email) {
        this(name, age);
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Person(String name, String age, String email, String sex) {
        this(name, age, email);
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

Таким образом вместо захламления дублем, копипаста кода в еще один конструктор - мы даем часть обязанностей в конструктор, который уже делает подобные вещи.

Если, например, есть штук 5 конструкторов с разными и множеством параметров - не придется копипастить код везде, а лишь перенаправить некоторые вещи с одного конструктора в другой.

Comment: Большое спасибо, понятно

Comment: @NikitaSamoylov: Если ответ помог, поставьте зелёную птичку слева от него.